# Magento - Add attribute if the product qty is zero

Tags: magento, if-statement

I want to insert this attrribute that I have created into the product page above the add to cart button but only if the qty is ZERO. Basically an estimated arrival date. Items that are available on back order only have a note above the add to cart button of when the product will actually be available from. I have put the below in and it works but I don't want it to show for products already available.

```
<p><font color="red">AVAILABLE FROM: <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('due_date')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></font></p>
```

Can someone let me know what I need to add please.

Most appreciated

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the stock quantity on the product page by using:

```
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()
```

You can then use that in a conditional to show the piece of code that you want. However, I'm not sure you need all of that to show the due date. Because you're already loading the product when you are on the product page, you should just be able to use:

```
<p class="red">AVAILABLE FROM: <?php echo $_product->getDueDate(); ?></p>
```

If that doesn't work, make sure that you have your due date attribute set to be visible on the product page. It'll be the one called, "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end".

Full code block could look something like this:

```
<?php
$qty = Mage::getModel(cataloginventory/stock_item)->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
if ($qty <= 0): ?>
<p class="red">AVAILABLE FROM: <?php echo $_product->getDueDate(); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you allow backorders, it's important you check for <= 0, rather than == 0. This is because if someone backorders it, your stock *will* go negative.

Also, it's more clean to remove the font tag and use CSS to style the text.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. I have tried adding in your block. It doesn't seem to work and the page does not load. I have reverted back to the code I posted initially as it does part of the job required. You have totally understood what I want though so I am guessing you were very close or I have done something wrong.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Also, it goes blank because there is a PHP error that is blocked from displaying - the error should have been recorded in either the system.log or exception.log file (assuming you are logging).

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 .    I will check the logs now. The screen doesn't go blank only the area where I have added the block code

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and get back to you in the next day or two if you're not able to debug yourself.

Comment: that would be great. Bit tied up with another product at the moment.